# Some nodes not being able to delete in AVL Tree in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, avl-tree

When deleting nodes from my AVL Tree, only certain nodes are able to get deleted and when I delete those other nodes, I get AttributeError.

```
from collections import deque

class AVL_Tree:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.height = 1

    def levelOrder_Traversal(self, root_node):
        if not root_node:
            return
        else:
            q = deque()
            q.append(root_node)
            while len(q) > 0:
                node = q.popleft()
                print(node.data)

                if node.left:
                    q.append(node.left)
                if node.right:
                    q.append(node.right)

    def get_height(self, root_node):
        if not root_node:
            return 0
        else: return root_node.height

    def get_balance(self, root_node):
        if not root_node:
            return 0
        else:
            return self.get_height(root_node.left) - self.get_height(root_node.right)

    def rotate_right(self, node):
        new_root = node.left
        node.left = new_root.right
        new_root.right = node

        node.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(node.left), self.get_height(node.right))
        new_root.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(new_root.left), self.get_height(new_root.right))

        return new_root

    def rotate_left(self, node):
        new_root = node.right
        node.right = new_root.left
        new_root.left = node

        node.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(node.left), self.get_height(node.right))
        new_root.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(new_root.left), self.get_height(new_root.right))

        return new_root

    def insert_data(self, root_node, new_data):
        if not root_node:
            return AVL_Tree(new_data)
        elif new_data < root_node.data:
            root_node.left = self.insert_data(root_node.left, new_data)
        else:
            root_node.right = self.insert_data(root_node.right, new_data)

        root_node.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(root_node.left), self.get_height(root_node.right))
        balance = self.get_balance(root_node)

        # left - left condition
        if balance > 1 and new_data < root_node.left.data:
            return self.rotate_right(root_node)
        
        # left - right condition
        if balance > 1 and new_data > root_node.left.data:
            root_node.left = self.rotate_left(root_node.left)
            return self.rotate_right(root_node)
        
        # right - right condition
        if balance < -1 and new_data > root_node.right.data:
            return self.rotate_left(root_node)
        
        # right - left condition
        if balance < -1 and new_data < root_node.right.data:
            root_node.right = self.rotate_right(root_node.right)
            return self.rotate_left(root_node)
        
        return root_node

    def get_min(self, root_node):
        current = root_node
        while current:
            current = current.left
        return current
    
    def delete_data(self, root_node, data):
        if not root_node:
            return root_node

        if data < root_node.data:
            root_node.left = self.delete_data(root_node.left, data)
        elif data > root_node.data:
            root_node.right = self.delete_data(root_node.right, data)
        else:
            if not root_node.left:
                temp = root_node.right
                root_node = None
                return temp
            elif not root_node.right:
                temp = root_node.left
                root_node = None
                return temp

            temp = self.get_min(root_node.right)
            root_node.data = temp.data
            root_node.right = self.delete_data(root_node.right, temp.data)

        root_node.height = 1 + max(self.get_height(root_node.left), self.get_height(root_node.right))
        balance = self.get_balance(root_node)

        # Left - Left condition
        if balance > 1 and self.get_balance(root_node.left) >= 0:
            return self.rotate_right(root_node)

        # Left - Right condition
        if balance > 1 and self.get_balance(root_node.left) < 0:
            root_node.left = self.rotate_left(root_node.left)
            return self.rotate_right(root_node)

        # Right - Right condition
        if balance < -1 and self.get_balance(root_node.right) <= 0:
            return self.rotate_left(root_node)

        # Right - Left condition
        if balance < -1 and self.get_balance(root_node.right) > 0:
            root_node.right = self.rotate_right(root_node.right)
            return self.rotate_left(root_node)

        return root_node
    

avl = AVL_Tree(30)

avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 25)
avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 35)
avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 20)
avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 15)
avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 5)
avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 10)
avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 50)
avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 60)
avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 70)
avl = avl.insert_data(avl, 65)

print("AVL Tree before deletion:")
avl.levelOrder_Traversal(avl)

print("\nAVL Tree after deleting data:")
avl = avl.delete_data(avl, 30)
avl.levelOrder_Traversal(avl)
```

In those nodes [ 20, 10, 50, 5, 15, 30, 65, 25, 35, 60, 70 ],
[ 20, 10, 50, 30, 65 ] ---> these five nodes raise AttributeError when I try to delete them.

I am self-studying data structures so I have no mentors or teachers to ask when I have problems. I tried chatgpt and google but I can't find answer for specific questions like this. So, I'm here asking for how I should fix my code.

I'd really appreciate if you guys can help me out. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: It seems the problem comes from `get_min` : it goes one step too far, so returns the left child of min (which is of course None) !

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes for your `get_min` method: it returns the left child of the node you seek, which is None! You can fix it very simply:

```
def get_min(self, root_node):
    current = root_node
    while current.left:
        current = current.left
    return current
```

With this fix, the `30` node is correctly deleted, and the traversal of the resulting tree is correct:

```
20 , 10 50, 5 15 35 65,  - - - - 25 - 60 70
```

(- added to better see the tree structure)

Comment: Well spotted, Swifty!

Comment: Oh well, I had fun looking up AVL trees on wikipedia, so I learnt something interesting in the process :) Plus I did some basic `print(...)` debugging.